# Gazebo and Rviz have different velocity when robot_localization package is used

Tags: robot-localization, ros-humble, ignition-fortress

ROS2 Humble, Gazebo Fortress, Gravity in gazebo set to zero.

I am trying to fuse IMU and GPS data with [robot_localization](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/tree/ros2) package.

Already went through the following [tutorial 1](http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/robot_localization/html/integrating_gps.html), [tutorial 2](https://navigation.ros.org/tutorials/docs/navigation2_with_gps.html).

I am publishing a static transform from map to odom.

The parameters are the following

```
ekf_filter_node_map:
  ros__parameters:
    frequency: 30.0
    two_d_mode: true  # Recommended to use 2d mode for nav2 in mostly planar environments
    print_diagnostics: true
    debug: false
    publish_tf: true

    map_frame: map
    odom_frame: odom
    base_link_frame: base_link # the frame id used by the turtlebot's diff drive plugin
    world_frame: odom

    odom0: odometry/gps
    odom0_config: [true,  true,  false,
                   false, false, false,
                   false, false, false,
                   false, false, false,
                   false, false, false]
    odom0_queue_size: 10
    odom0_differential: false
    odom0_relative: false

    imu0: imu/data
    imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                  false,  false,  true,
                  false, false, false,
                  false,  false,  false,
                  false,  false,  false]
    imu0_differential: false  # If using a real robot you might want to set this to true, since usually absolute measurements from real imu's are not very accurate
    imu0_relative: false
    imu0_queue_size: 10
    imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

    use_control: false

    process_noise_covariance: [ 1e-3, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                0.0,    1e-3,  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                0.0,    0.0,    1e-3,  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3,   0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3,   0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.00000005,  0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.005,    0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.005,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.001,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    3.0,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    3.0,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    3.0,   0.0,    0.0,
                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    3.0,   0.0,
                                0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    3.0 ]


navsat_transform:
  ros__parameters:
    frequency: 30.0
    delay: 3.0
    magnetic_declination_radians: 0.0
    yaw_offset: 0.0
    zero_altitude: true
    broadcast_utm_transform: true
    publish_filtered_gps: true
    use_odometry_yaw: true
    wait_for_datum: false
```

I tried several values for the `process_noise_convariance` but I see that the velocity in gazebo and Rviz dont match when I sent a Twist msg with only z angular velocity. This [video](https://youtu.be/-i-gWCwUhrw) explains it better I think. If I use ground truth odometry from gazebo, then the robot could reach a target goal but with robot_localization , this doesnt happen.

Is there something else that I could try out to get the localization working? Any help would be great

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the simulated IMU in gazebo fortress was already giving me filtered data (`imu/data` as per imu_filter_madgwick). I thought it would be raw `imu/data_raw` and used [imu_filter_madgwick](http://wiki.ros.org/imu_filter_madgwick) to filter it again which made the orientation estimation wrong.